# Use Jest to mock external user module in an imported module

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I don't know if I'm missing something in the docs, but I have this situation:

```
// test.js

import User from './user'

it("should load initial data", async() => {
  const users = new User()
  const user = await users.load()
})

// User.js

import Api from './api'

export default class User {
  async load() {
    const res = await Api.fetch() // prevent/mock this in testing
  }
}
```

What is the Jest-way to prevent/mock the external `Api` module in `User.js`. I do not want `User.js` to make a real network request within the test.

Further to this, I'm looking for a more generic mocking solution, ie. say I'm testing in React Native, and I want to mock `NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale`, for example. Lets say `Api.fetch()` calls the line above, and doesn't make a HTTP request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) in combination with [mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api) like  [mockImplementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) will provide what you are looking for.

Here is a working example:

```
// ---- api.js ----
export const getData = () => {
  return Promise.resolve('hi');
}


// ---- user.js ----
import { getData } from './api'

export default class User {
  async load() {
    return await getData(); // mock this call in user.test.js
  }
}


// ---- user.test.js ----
import User from './user'
import * as Api from './api'; // import * so we can mock 'getData' on Api object

describe('User', () => {
  it('should load initial data', async() => {
    const mock = jest.spyOn(Api, 'getData'); // create a spy
    mock.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('hello')); // give it a mock implementation

    const user = new User();
    const result = await user.load();
    expect(result).toBe('hello');  // SUCCESS, mock implementation called

    mock.mockRestore(); // restore original implementation when we are done
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh nice, so you import the module into the test file, even if it's not directly related to the test (ie. the test file doesn't use Api, but User does)

Comment: yep!  import anything you want to mock.  `Jest` will replace the implementation so any code using it anywhere during the test will use the mock implementation instead

Comment: I think that was the missing piece of the puzzle! Thanks

Comment: Why should we invoke `mock.mockRestore();` - is it necessary? What are the ramifications of not doing it?

Comment: @lonix [`mockRestore`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore) is optional, just be aware that if `mockRestore` is not called the function will remain mocked *for the rest of the tests in that particular test file*.  If you leave it mocked for all of the tests be aware that it will remember *all* calls to it across all of the tests, you can use [`mockClear`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear) to clear the previous calls as needed.

Comment: "...rest of the tests in **that particular test file**" - that's what I wasn't sure of, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mock responses to HTTP requests, then you should check out [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock). It has a clean API that allows a lot of flexibility in creating HTTP responses to specific requests.

Comment: I agree. But I'm looking for a more generic mocking solution, ie. say I'm testing in React Native, and I want to mock `NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale`, for example. Lets say `Api.fetch()` calls the line above, and doesn't make a HTTP request

Comment: @benhowdle89 Then you need to edit your question to be more clear about what you are asking.